# Get File Path of a System.Drawing.Bitmap

Tags: vb.net

**Is there a way to get the File Path of a `System.Drawing.Bitmap` Type?**

Something like:

`My.Resources.myImg.GetFilePath` Or

`GetFilePath(My.Resources.myImg)`

Obviously my above example does not exist. I am just showing my intention.

Comment: In general, a bitmap is an object in memory. It may not have been read from a file, so it doesn't necessarily have a file path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty sure this isn't possible as there's quite a few ways to init a System.Drawing.Bitmap (e.g: Stream, Uri, another image object) and this Bitmap is a very generic object.

Depending on the technology you're using, there may be a more specialized image type that's better to use. For example, if you're using WPF, check out *BitmapImage* which does store the file path as the property *UriSource*.

If you really need to work with System.Drawing.Bitmaps, I'd recommend creating a model that houses both the bitmap and the file path. Like this:

```
{
    public Bitmap MyImage {get; set; }
    public string FilePath {get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not so sure the resources has a path, I think they're embedded in the application and then read into the memory *(I could be wrong however)*.

If you want them to have a path you'd have to save them to a file. This saves the image in the Local Application Data folder:

```
Dim MyImgPath As String = IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "myImg.bmp")
My.Resources.myImg.Save(MyImgPath, Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp)
```

If you want to save the image in the same folder as your application:

```
Dim MyImgPath As String = IO.Path.Combine(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory(), "myImg.bmp")
```

Comment: I actually do have the file in my `Resources` folder and could hard code it. That's kind of what I am trying to avoid. The problem is I'm working with someone else's function that expects a string.

Comment: @Chris : The `My Project\Resources` folder won't exist _after_ you've compiled the application. As far as I'm aware you need to write the resources to a file.

Comment: Try taking out only the .exe and run it on another computer. You will still have the images although you have not copied any images with it. Your `Resources` folder won't matter after you've compiled the application, so in order to get a file path from an image: save it every time you need it.

Comment: I have the resource set to copy to output directory. I know this isn't the best way to do it but the existing code base I am working with has functions I am not aloud to touch that take strings as parameters for image paths. Right now they have it dependent on a network resource. I am just trying to create a local fallback that is just a tiny bit more dependable than a file on a network

Comment: @Chris : If you set the resource to `Copy to output directory` then why do you have it as a resource? Use either or, or else you'd have one embedded image and one image saved on disk. In order to simply move your app around, I'd recommend to use the image as a normal resource (`My.Resources`) and then writing it to the disk when needed (as shown above).

Answer (score 0):

You might want to create your own object:

```
Public Class MyBitmap 
Inherits Bitmap 

Private _FilePath As String 
'------------------------'

Public Property FilePath as String 
Get 
Return _FilePath
End Get 

' etc...
```

The you could set the path and get it later on from the property

Comment: That won't do for resources though. Besides, you don't need `Private _FilePath As String`, you only need this line: `Public Property FilePath as String`.

Comment: You might be right on this one, but I think it's better to have the variable in the class itself, too.

Comment: It doesn't actually make much of a difference unless you use ReadOnly properties or custom actions when setting/getting, otherwise they're both the same. The compiler creates the variable for you if there is none, anyway. :)

Comment: Yeah but I learned it that way in Java at school and got a habit out of it.

Comment: Y'know old habits die hard

Comment: It's okay to do that, I didn't say that :). It's just... unnecessary... for VB.NET. (: